# Переместить файлы в каталоги на основании суффикса («расширения»)

Tags: linux, bash, unix

У меня в папке находятся файлы разных расширений. Как можно создать отдельную папку для каждого отдельного расширения (например с названием расширения) и записать туда все файлы этого расширения?

Узнать существущие расширения можно с помощью:

```
find . -type f -name "*.*" | awk -F. '{print $NF}' | sort -u | paste -s -d,
```

Comment: сформулируйте, пожалуйста, сам **вопрос**. внести изменения можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса.

Comment: Спасибо за совет, уже подправил

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Предлагаю полученный после sort список расширений преобразовать в команды, которые создадут папки и скопируют/переместят файлы. И подать эти команды на вход bash, примерно так:

```
find . -type f -name "*.*" | awk -F. '{print $NF}' | sort -u | sed 's/\(.*\)/mkdir \1; cp *.\1 \1\//' | bash
```

Comment: Просто замечательно! Это как раз то, что я искал. Большое спасибо

Comment: @user205638 главное, что бы не оказалось файла, например с именем `test.1;echo rm *`, он заставит bash выполнить немного не то, что хотелось изначально :) Это конечно маловероятно, но подобный хак скрипта теоретически возможен.

Comment: Надеюсь на такое не наткнусь :) Но Ваш метод мне очень понравился, элегантно. Мне по сути нужно для того, что бы сделать "отчет" о сущестующих файлах в папке (для каждогого расширения отельно).
То есть количество файлов с расширенимем .ххх, максимальный размер, минимальный размер и так далее. 
И другого метода как записать все в отдельную папку а потом  оттуда счиать я не придумал :)

Answer (score 1):

1. программе *find* логично было бы передать опцию `-maxdepth 1`, чтобы поиск проводился только в текущем каталоге, без вложенных каталогов.
2. после `sort -u` у вас уже есть список суффиксов, следующее преобразование `paste -s -d,`, превращающее список в строку, где суффиксы разделены запятой, излишне.
3. с этим списком можно, например, с помощью программы *xargs*, произвести необходимые действия: и каталог создать, и файлы переместить:

   ```
   xargs -n 1 -I% sh -c 'mkdir -p %; mv *.% %'
   ```

демонстрация:

```
$ touch file file.tar.gz file.tar file.gz
$ tree
.
├── file
├── file.gz
├── file.tar
└── file.tar.gz

0 directories, 4 files
$ find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -name "*.*" | awk -F. '{print $NF}' \
 | sort -u | xargs -n 1 -I% sh -c 'mkdir -p %; mv *.% %'
$ tree
.
├── file
├── gz
│   ├── file.gz
│   └── file.tar.gz
└── tar
    └── file.tar

2 directories, 4 files
```

доп. информация: [`man find`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/find.1.html), [`man xargs`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/xargs.1.html).

---

дополнение:

если требуется перекладывание файлов **и** из вложенных каталогов, а не только из текущего, то логика должна быть несколько изменена. например, так:

```
$ find . -type f -name "*.*" |  while read f; do s="${f##*.}"; mkdir -p "$s"; mv "$f" "$s"; done
```

имена взяты в кавычки для корректной обработки файлов, содержащих в имени пробелы.

Comment: Дело в том, что это задание по проекту, и расширения должны быть заделены запятой по условию :) Так же, поиск должен осуществляться и в подкаталогах

Comment: Программа xargs  создат требуемые каталоги, если файл с необходимым расширенем находится в подкаталоге(не в основной папке)?

Comment: если **вам** для чего-то нужен не список, а строка, разделённая запятыми — нет проблем. для создания каталогов и перемещения файлов такая строка абсолютно бесполезна. если вам надо перекладывать в созданные каталоги **и** файлы из подкаталогов, то логика должна быть совершенно иная: предложенный вами конвейер не нужен.

Comment: *Программа xargs создат* — нет, она ничего не создаст. она выполнит то, что передано ей аргументами: `mkdir ...` и `mv ...`

Comment: @user205638, я дополнил ответ.